# How can I use SPI signals?

Tags: intel, spi, datasheet, motherboard, chipset

I've recently started to read [this](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/7-series-chipset-pch-datasheet.pdf) intel's datasheet, but I don't understand section 2.16

[image]

This section shows the name of SPI signals and a short description of it.

The point is, how can I use that signals? Is there any way to "play" with that signals using assembly or any other language?

Comment: Those are chipset pins, not part of the CPU and not something that has any special asm instructions associated with it.  You'd need a driver (that uses PCIe writes and reads) to some MMIO port or ports, I think.  (i.e. normal stores and/or loads).

Comment: Looks like you are looking at the description of the SPI NOR controller. On Intel it’s used to connect flash chip with firmware.

Comment: I have eventually looked into the datasheet and it seems to me that I'm right (see chapter 22).