# Is there any command to write to BIOS in intel PCH chipset?

Tags: command, intel, bios, opcode, chipset

I have took a look at the PCH chipset datasheet. There is a lot of information and commands, but I can't find any opcode to write to the BIOS

[image]

How can I write to BIOS with PCH chipset?

Comment: A screenshot of a web browser is not a very useful way to present the text you're talking about.  At least link Intel's manual.  And like your previous question ([How can I use SPI signals?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66393966)), of course there's no CPU instruction for it, these are I/O components that you interact with by doing normal driver stuff, with MMIO loads/stores (and maybe `in` / `out` instructions).  x86 is a von Neumann architecture (not Harvard); not like AVR where there's a `lpm` (load program memory) to load from flash instead of RAM.

Comment: In the Linux kernel the driver for that is called intel-spi under spi-nor subsystem: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/mtd/spi-nor/controllers/intel-spi.c (@PeterCordes, JFYI)